# Given a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, find a prime number close to $z$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a large integer $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, what algorithms are available to compute a prime number larger than $z$ and close to $z$, efficiently, but not necessarily the closest?

e.g. Given the number $400$, any of $\{401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, ...\}$, would be acceptable.

Noting that for large integers, the solutions aren't so trivial to compute.

Comment: How big is the number and how efficiently do you need the answer? If the number is not so big, you can reduce to a subset of numbers close to the number and test likely candidates. Do you need to do it by hand or using a computer?

Comment: The numbers are large, over 200 decimal digits. O(log(n)^2) or better, would be good.

Comment: My second prototype will be written in C, using GMP. Note that there's a function in GMP, mpz_nextprime, which I may be able to use. However, the documentation doesn't name or describe the algorithm used.

Comment: Yikes, that is a pretty big number! This is not my area, but as far as I understand it, primality tests for numbers so large are computationally expensive in the general case. For encryption, they generally generate large numbers that are very, very likely to be prime, but not necessarily so. These are, I think, 100 digit primes. I would suspect that determining the primality of numbers 'close' to a 200 digit integer would be pretty difficult, but again I would defer to someone who knows more detail than me.

Comment: Head to the *[**Alpertron***](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) and type in `N(x)` for any integer `x`. This will compute the next probable prime very *very* quickly.

Comment: $200$ digits is nothing for primality tests, however factoring a number of this magnitude can be a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* gives the next prime blazingly fast:

```
NextPrime[10^{617}]
```

$10^{617} + 2607$

in $0.858659$ seconds.

That oughta suffice....

(You can enter this code for free on WolframAlpha.com)

Although *Mathematica* doesn't state the upper limitation of their algorithm, I think that is moot, in practice. (The OP asked about neighboring primes to 400 and wasn't concerned that the algorithm get the *closest* prime.)

---

Without you specifying the criteria for membership in your subset, we can never help you.

Comment: How does the algorithm work?

Comment: That (0.004117 seconds) is fast. I tried using RSA-617 (with 617 decimal digits) as input. I wasn't sure how to time it, but the output was almost instantaneous. Hopefully, GMP will be just as fast.

Comment: I am somewhat suspicious of this. Mathematica doesn't seem to indicate that there is any upper bound for this function's effectiveness, which does not seem to make sense. Primality tests are probabilistic or deterministic. They could be implementing a particular probabilistic test or a deterministic one. I am not sure if there are more successful deterministic tests but the AKS test is only solvable in polynomial time which scales up significantly as the number of digits do. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test. If it is probabilistic, then we don't know how certain the answer is.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Head to the *[**Alpertron***](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) and type in `N(x)` for any integer `x`. This will compute the next probable prime very *very* quickly.

Comment: @user477343:  Wow... Yeah!  Problem solved!